# Kotlin: Create a regular array as in Java

Tags: java, kotlin

For example, in Java I can create such an array with this syntax:

`Thing box = new Thing[10];`

In Kotlin such syntax can't be used. I would like to create the equivalent of above in Kotlin.

I have found the `Array(size: Int, init: Int -> T)` methods but it requires that I specify an init lambda that will not allow me to use `null`. I want to have an array filled with `null` or some equivalent of the size that I want.

**The scenario:** I need to have an array of packet handlers where the index of the handler is the packet's opcode.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use [`arrayOfNulls()`](http://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/array-of-nulls.html). Naturally, your array will be of nullable type. Alternatively, just use a list.