# How can I create an array in Kotlin like in Java by just providing a size?

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, kotlin

How can I create a Array like we do in java?

```
int A[] = new int[N];
```

How can I do this in Kotlin?

Comment: I know you are asking about `int`, but for Objects, there is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32679060/kotlin-create-a-regular-array-as-in-java

Answer (score 223, accepted):

According to the [reference](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/basic-types.html#arrays), arrays are created in the following way:

- For Java's primitive types there are distinct types `IntArray`, `DoubleArray` etc. which store [unboxed](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html) values.

  They are created with the corresponding constructors and factory functions:

  ```kotlin
  val arrayOfZeros = IntArray(size) //equivalent in Java: new int[size]
  val numbersFromOne = IntArray(size) { it + 1 }
  val myInts = intArrayOf(1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21)
  ```

  The first one is simillar to that in Java, it just creates a primitive array filled with the default value, e.g. zero for `Int`, `false` for `Boolean`.
- Non primitive-arrays are represented by `Array<T>` class, where `T` is the items type.

  `T` can still be one of types primitive in Java (`Int`, `Boolean`,...), but the values inside will be boxed equivalently to Java's `Integer`, `Double` and so on.

  Also, `T` can be both [nullable and non-null](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/null-safety.html) like `String` and `String?`.

  These are created in a similar way:

  ```kotlin
  val nulls = arrayOfNulls<String>(size) //equivalent in Java: new String[size]
  val strings = Array(size) { "n = $it" } 
  val myStrings = arrayOf("foo", "bar", "baz")

  val boxedInts = arrayOfNulls<Int>(size) //equivalent in Java: new Integer[size]
  val boxedZeros = Array(size) { 0 }
  ```

Comment: `Array<Int>(size)` doesn't compile. That's because you can't create a non-nullable array without providing the elements.

Comment: @KirillRakhman, thanks for your remark, that was an inadvertent mistake. Fixed.

Answer (score 11):

Here is simple example of init of Array of String

```
        var names = Array<String>(<AnotherArray.size>) { i -> "" }
```

Kotlin [doc](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-array/)

Comment: In practice, it looks like this `val array = Array<String?>(10){""}` where 10 is me saying an array of 10 empty strings

Answer (score 2):

In Kotlin, creating an IntArray of size N is simple. Use `IntArray(n)` or the appropriate type, as detailed thoroughly in hotkey's answer.

When utilizing your fixed size array, you can use [Kotlin Destructuring](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/multi-declarations.html)

```
// Create fixed sized array
val point = IntArray(2)

// Access values directly
val (x, y) = point
```

In this case, `x` will be taken from index 0, `y` from index 1, etc.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to create an array of Primitive Types, you can simply use the constructors:

Example: to create an array of integers with size N.

```kotlin
val arr = IntArray(size = N)
```

For non-primitive types, you can use `arrayOfNulls<Type>()`.

Comment: Wow that works (arrayOfNulls), but it would have taken me years to figure that out.  Thank god kotlin is so obvious and intuitive!

Answer (score 1):

You can create it using     `IntArray`  like this declaration for variable
`val A = IntArray(N)`

Answer (score -2):

val A = FloatArray(N) //N being the size of the ar

Comment: The OP needs an array of integer, not floats.