# Different Between ArrayList, IntArray and Array<Int>

Tags: java, kotlin

I am new in Java and Kotlin.

Recently when I read a tutorial while learning Kotlin.

I found there are some `Array/List` confusing me.

1. What is the different between `ArrayList`, `IntArray` and `Array<Int>`?
2. When should I use them?

Comment: On the java side there is the fixed sized array: `int[]` (with the primitive type `int`) and dynamically sized `ArrayList<Integer>` (with the int wrapper Integer).

Comment: This question basically duplicates two other questions: (1) [Difference between List and Array types in Kotlin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36262305/difference-between-list-and-array-types-in-kotlin) and (2) [IntArray vs Array<Int> in Kotlin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45090808/intarray-vs-arrayint-in-kotlin)

Comment: @hotkey alright. thank you for pointing it out.

Answer (score 4):

Major differences

`ArrayList` : resizable, Generic (Objects)

`IntArray` : primitive, fix length, only Int values

`Array<Int>` : Generic (Objects), fix length

Answer (score 3):

I see multiples questions inside of your question and i gonna attempt to help you.

### First question: What is the difference between `ArrayList` and `List`:

- `Array` is static in size, `ArrayList` is autoresizable.
- `ArrayList` can not contains primitive types *(like `int`, `char`, ...)*, `List` can.

### Second question: What is the difference between `Array<Int>` and `IntArray`

Check this question who respond to this question:  [IntArray vs Array<Int> in Kotlin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45090808/intarray-vs-arrayint-in-kotlin)

but in summary:

```
Array<Int> == Integer[] 
IntArray == int[]
```

That's it !

Answer (score 0):

This will partially answer your question: [**Difference between List and Array types in Kotlin**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36262305/difference-between-list-and-array-types-in-kotlin)

Besides, the difference between `IntArray` and `Array<Int>` is the same as between Java `int[]` and `Integer[]`: the former stores primitive integers without wrapping them while the latter [boxes them into `java.lang.Integer`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html) objects. Consider `IntArray` an optimized form of `Array<Int>` that does not introduce memory and boxing-unboxing overheads.