# How to apply map function to array in Kotlin and change its values?

Tags: arrays, kotlin

I am working with this code.

```
fun main(args : Array<String>){

    val someArray : Array<Int> =  arrayOf(3,53,2,521,51,23,512,34,124);

    println("Original array is ")

    someArray.forEach {print("$it , ")}

    someArray.map({num -> num*2})

    println("Changed array is ")

    println()

    someArray.forEach { print("$it , ") }
}
```

But the map function does not seem to work. Here is what it prints

Original array is 
3 , 53 , 2 , 521 , 51 , 23 , 512 , 34 , 124 , Changed array is

3 , 53 , 2 , 521 , 51 , 23 , 512 , 34 , 124 ,

My question is why is the array not doubling the value of its elements? What i am i missing here?

Comment: You need to assign this array to another array.

Comment: I don''t want to do that , how do i modify the existing array?

Comment: Change the `val someArray` to `var someArray`. Then `someArray = someArray.map({num -> num*2})`

Comment: Ok , is there any in which i can modify it without assiging it?

Comment: Yes! Change the `val` to `var` to make it mutable. Then assign the result of the map to the same variable. That's what I meant in the previous comment.

Comment: What's wrong with re-assignment?

Comment: I understand what you are saying. My Question is , can i do this with a single function , like `someArray.someFunction({num -> num*2})` which will modify the elements ?

Comment: No! You can't. Because they are value types. Modification to any of them creates new item.

Comment: OK thanks for the help

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You could always define your own extension that does what you need:

```
fun <T> Array<T>.mapInPlace(transform: (T) -> T) {
    for (i in this.indices) {
        this[i] = transform(this[i])
    }
}
```

Usage would look like this:

```
someArray.mapInPlace { num -> num * 2 }
```

Note that there are special non-generic classes for primitive arrays, such as [`IntArray`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-int-array/index.html) (see also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45090808/4465208)), so you should probably be using those instead of the generic one. Of course then you'd have to define this extension for each of them separately, like:

```
fun IntArray.mapInPlace(transform: (Int) -> Int) { ... }
fun DoubleArray.mapInPlace(transform: (Double) -> Double) { ... }
```

Answer (score 10):

From the documentation, [`map`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/map.html) doesn't modify the items in place but rather returns a `List` containing the result of the mapping function applied to all the items:

> Returns a list containing the results of applying the given transform function to each element in the original array [or collection or map, depending on the receiver].

So, to get the expected result you should do something like:

```
val doubled = someArray.map { n -> n * 2}
doubled.forEach { print("$it , ") }
```

### EDIT

From what I know **there's no built-in function allowing you to map items in-place**. However, in your case you're dealing with an `Array`, which is a mutable data structure, so the alternative is to use an old-style loop to iteratively transform its items (you can apply the same logic with `MutableList` or other mutable data structures using an `Iterator` to update values). Something like this:

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val someArray: Array<Int> = arrayOf(3, 53, 2, 521, 51, 23, 512, 34, 124);

    someArray.forEach { print("$it , ") }

    println()

    for (i in 0 until someArray.size) {
        someArray[i] = someArray[i] * 2
    }

    someArray.forEach { print("$it , ") }
}
```

Comment: Ok , is there any in which i can modify it without creating a new variable?

Answer (score 6):

An alternative is to use `forEachIndexed` instead of `map`. Replace

```
someArray.map({num -> num*2})
```

by

```
someArray.forEachIndexed{ index, num -> someArray[index] = num * 2 }
```

Answer (score 2):

As many have stated, the map returns a new list and doesn't modify the original.

The most efficient way to rewrite your intended code is to do

```
// assuming you want to act upon individual elements in the list
fun main(args : Array<String>) {
    val someArray : Array<Int> =  arrayOf(3,53,2,521,51,23,512,34,124);
    println("Original array is $someArray")
    someArray
        .map { it * 2 }
        .forEach { print("$it , ") }
}
```

or if you just want to see the comma separated list of values

```
// really just want to print the transformed values instead
fun main(args : Array<String>) {
    val someArray : Array<Int> =  arrayOf(3,53,2,521,51,23,512,34,124);
    println("Original array is $someArray")
    someArray
        .map { it * 2 }
        .also { print(it.joinToString()) }
}
```