# Kotlin initialize an Array using another array

Tags: arrays, indexing, kotlin, initialization

I can initialize an array in Kotlin like this:

`val mArr = Array<Int>(5) {0}`

and I'll have the following array `[0,0,0,0,0]`

The thing is, I need to initialise an array and put the values of another array into it.
i.e:

`initialArray = [1, 4, 5 ,-2, 7]
 val offset = 5`

And should get `mArr = [6, 9, 10, 3, 12]`

Is there a way to set the value of each `mArr[i]` based on each `initialArray[i]`?

Something like

`val mArr = Array<Int>(initialArray.size) { offset + initialArray[index]}`

Without wrapping it in a `for loop`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is `map` function for array.

So:

```
val initialArray = arrayOf(1, 4, 5 ,-2, 7)
val offset = 5
val newArray = initialArray.map { it + offset }.toTypedArray()
```

But this way you create new array without modifying the old one.
If you want modify old array you can use `forEachIndexed` extension method:

```
initialArray.forEachIndexed { index, value ->
    initialArray[index] = initialArray[index] + offset

    // or:
    initialArray[index] = value + offset
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
val mArr = Array<Int>(initialArray.size) { offset + initialArray[index] }
```

already nearly works. It's just that `index` isn't defined here. You want it to be the function's parameter, so `{ index -> offset + initialArray[index] }` or shorter `{ offset + initialArray[it] }`. Also, for this you probably want [`IntArray` instead of `Array<Int>`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45090808/intarray-vs-arrayint-in-kotlin) (and for `initialArray` as well). Combining these changes:

```
val mArr = IntArray(initialArray.size) { offset + initialArray[it] }
```

Comment: `it` is the value inside the array, not the index. The answer i received below worked for me

Comment: No, `it` is the default name for the lambda's parameter (see https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/lambdas.html#it-implicit-name-of-a-single-parameter). In `map` it will be the value inside the array; in `IntArray`'s constructor it will be the index.