# Kotlin - How to create a dynamic matrix?

Tags: kotlin

I want to create a matrix of size `nxn` where n is the length of input `message:String`.
So far this is the only solution that came to my mind and that too has four for loops.

```
fun main(){
println("Enter the message:")
var message:String = readLine().toString()
var cipher = Array(message.length) { Array<Int>(message.length) {0} }
for(i in 0 .. (message.length - 1)){
    for(j in 0 .. (message.length - 1)){
        cipher[i][j] = readLine()!!.toInt()
    }
}
//print the matrix
for(i in 0..(message.length -1)){
    for(j in 0..(message.length -1)){
        print(cipher[i][j])
    }
    println()
   }
}
```

Is there any less complex code for the same? How can I improve this code?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assuming your input data is [row-major](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row-_and_column-major_order), this *can* be simplified by moving the array filling logic into the array creation itself:

```
var cipher = Array(message.length) {
    IntArray(message.length) { readLine()!!.toInt() }
}
```

`Array`'s constructor takes an initializer function that is invoked `size` times to populate the array. By reading user input here, you can populate the array while the matrix is being created and avoid having to write an extra loop.

---

Miscellaneous notes:

- `readLine().toString()` is redundant and possibly harmful. `readLine` returns a `String?`, and you invoke `Any?.toString` on it, which either returns the result of `Any.toString` if its receiver is not null, or the literal string `"null"` (which is probably *not* desired.)
- Consider using the `until` infix function when looping over arrays (`0 until length`), rather than `0..(length - 1)` (or, even better, the `Array.indices` extension property.)
- Consider using the corresponding primitive array type (i.e. `IntArray`, `FloatArray`, etc. rather than `Array<*>`)

See also:

- [`readLine`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.io/read-line.html)
- [`Any?.toString`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/to-string.html)
- [`until`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.ranges/until.html)
- [`indices`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/indices.html)
- [IntArray vs Array<Int> in Kotlin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45090808/intarray-vs-arrayint-in-kotlin)

You can also avoid your output loop entirely by simplifying your code:

```
println(cipher.joinToString("\n") { row -> row.joinToString("") })
```

---

Here's a simpler piece of code:

```
fun main() {
    println("Enter the message:")
    
    var message = readLine()!!
    var cipher = Array(message.length) {
        IntArray(message.length) { readLine()!!.toInt() }
    }
    
    println(cipher.joinToString("\n") { it.joinToString("") })
}
```