# Kotlin -> Java API call is not using the method I want because varargs method is swallowing all method arguments

Tags: java, kotlin

I'm calling a Spring method from Kotlin and Spring provides 2 signatures, one that takes 2 args (the second being varargs) and one that takes 3 args.

I want to call the 3-arg method, but I can't figure out how to match the types - it keeps calling the 2-arg version with the varargs slurping the values.

Here are the method signatures (I want to call the first, but it keeps calling the second):

```
@Override
public int update(String sql, Object[] args, int[] argTypes) throws DataAccessException {
    return update(sql, newArgTypePreparedStatementSetter(args, argTypes));
}

@Override
public int update(String sql, @Nullable Object... args) throws DataAccessException {
    return update(sql, newArgPreparedStatementSetter(args));
}
```

Here is my Kotlin code:

```
var sql = "INSERT INTO \"$sourceTable\" ($insertList) VALUES ($valueList)"
val p: Array<Any?> = params.toTypedArray()
val c: Array<Int> = columnTypes.toTypedArray()
targetJdbcTemplate.update(sql, p, c)
```

Clearly, something is going wrong and Array does not map to Object[], because my debugger shows me that I am calling the second method here, not the first.

How can I make Kotlin understand which method I want? How do I map `Array<Any?>` `Array<Int>` to `Object[]` and `Int[]` so the compiler will understand?

Comment: In Kotlin `Array<Int>` is a `Integer[]` under the hood, and `IntArray` is an `int[]` (more info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45094889/2446208)). Not sure if it will help in this case but does changing `c` to [`c.toIntArray()`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/to-int-array.html#tointarray) on the last line solve the problem?

Comment: Put that in an answer so I can mark it correct - and thanks!

Comment: Glad it worked out! Just posted it as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Kotlin `Array<Int>` is a `Integer[]` under the hood, and `IntArray` is an `int[]` (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45094889/2446208)).

To resolve the issue, you can change `c` to [`c.toIntArray()`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/to-int-array.html#tointarray) on the last line:

```kotlin
targetJdbcTemplate.update(sql, p, c.toIntArray())
```

Answer (score 1):

When doing Kotlin -> Java interrop, Kotlin has specific Array types to help deal with this kind of ambiguous Type.

In this case you will want to use `IntArray` in Kotlin to map to the proper type in Java

There are a number of other Primitive array types such as:
ByteArray, ShortArray, IntArray

Reference:
https://kotlinlang.org/docs/arrays.html#primitive-type-arrays