# Kotlin fixed array of strings

Tags: java, arrays, kotlin

is it possible to create fixed size array of strings using Kotlin like in Java ?

something like `val arrayOfString: Array(5)`

Comment: _val arr = Array(5) { "" }_. See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35253368/how-can-i-create-an-array-in-kotlin-like-in-java-by-just-providing-a-size

Answer (score 3):

Sort of.

In Kotlin, you can't have `val arrayOfString : Array<String> = Array(5)`, because the values filling the array would be null, and null isn't a valid value of `String`.

You can have `val arrayOfString: Array<String?> = arrayOfNulls(5)`, or you can have `val arrayOfString : Array<String> = Array(5) { "defaultString" }`.